# Compare data from text file with data from MS Access

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I know how to compare two text file using vb.net but is there a way to compare a data in text file with the data from MS access?
For example the data from the text file consists of:

```
Orange
Banana  
Strawberry
Mango
Watermelon
```

and MS access consists of:

```
Orange
Banana
Strawberry
Blueberry
Apple
```

The output will be
Blueberry and Apple.

Is there a way to query the data from access and compare it with the data in the text file?

Comment: Not the downvoter or the closevoter, but put the text file into an Access table, and compare from there.  Easy peasy.

Comment: U mean import the text file into access?

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question as asked, of course there's a way.  How do you do it for two files?  You don't compare the files directly, do you?  You read the data into your application as `String` objects and then compare those.  you do the same regardless of the source of the data.  In this case, read the file exactly as you already know how and then query the database to get the data it contains and then compare as before.  If you don't know how to query a database then that's what you need to research  There is plenty of information out there.  Just search the web for the obvious, i.e. *vb.net access database*.

Comment: Thanks jmcilhinney. All I need is some idea on how to since I'm new to programming. Thank you

Comment: This site is not for that purpose.  It is for providing answers to specific questions.  The fact that you're new doesn't mean that you need us to tell you what to do.  There are plenty of tutorials and other resources out there that hundreds of new developers use every day.  If they can do it, you can too, unless you are unable to use a search engine for some reason.